# NGINX as warm cache in front of wowza for HLS live streams - problem during live streaming with securetoken an many of 1 channel?

Tags: caching, video-streaming, nginx-reverse-proxy, wowza

I'we configured nginx as wowza cache; wowza has an http origin application with playback security enabled and transcoder enabled that creates 2 streaming with different bitrate for serve adaptive bitrate. After some time and randomly, ngnix give 403 retriving media chunk and 200 retriving chunklist; when this happens the live stream stops working fine looping video for some time. In VLC debug i can see that the client try to call the media chunks but nothing is served. From inspect web traffic i see 403 on mediachunk and 200 on chinklist and chunklist does not change. This behavior gets worse if I configure on the wowza more of one streams. On wowza log I can see that randomly wowza refuse the request from nginx. Any help is appreciated.

I tried to reduce the source bitrate an some parameter like cache duration and max age.